# Performance issue with boost transform_iterator and counting_iterator

Tags: c++, performance, boost, functional-programming

I am currently trying to benchmark various implementations of large loop performing arbitrary jobs, and I found myself with a very slow version when using boost transform iterators and boost counting_iterators.

I designed a small code that benchmark two loops that sums the product of all integers between 0 and SIZE-1 with an arbitrary integer (that I choose to be 1 in my example in order to avoid overflow).

Her's my code:

```
//STL
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

//Boost
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

//Compile using
// g++ ./main.cpp -o test -std=c++11

//Launch using
// ./test 1

#define NRUN 10
#define SIZE 128*1024*1024

struct MultiplyByN
{
    MultiplyByN( size_t N ): m_N(N){};
    size_t operator()(int i) const { return i*m_N; }
    const size_t m_N;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int N = std::stoi( argv[1] );
    size_t sum = 0;
    //Initialize chrono helpers
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto diff = stop - start;
    double msec=std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); //Set min runtime to ridiculously high value
    MultiplyByN op(N);


    //Perform multiple run in order to get minimal runtime
    for(int k = 0; k< NRUN; k++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            sum += op(i);
        }
        stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        diff = stop - start;
        //Compute minimum runtime
        msec = std::min( msec, std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() );
    }
    std::cout << "First version : Sum of values is "<< sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "First version : Minimal Runtime was "<< msec << " msec "<< std::endl;
    msec=std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); //Reset min runtime to ridiculously high value

    //Perform multiple run in order to get minimal runtime
    for(int k = 0; k< NRUN; k++)
    {
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        //Functional way to express the summation
        sum = std::accumulate(  boost::make_transform_iterator(boost::make_counting_iterator(0), op ),
                        boost::make_transform_iterator(boost::make_counting_iterator(SIZE), op ),
                        (size_t)0, std::plus<size_t>() );

        stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        diff = stop - start;
        //Compute minimum runtime
        msec = std::min( msec, std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() );
    }
    std::cout << "Second version : Sum of values is "<< sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Second version version : Minimal Runtime was "<< msec << " msec "<< std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the output I get:

```
./test 1
First version : Sum of values is 9007199187632128
First version : Minimal Runtime was 433.142 msec 
Second version : Sum of values is 9007199187632128
Second version version : Minimal Runtime was 10910.7 msec
```

The "functional" version of my loop that uses std::accumulate is 25 times slower than the simple loop version, why so ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Did you compile with compiler optimizations enabled? (-O2 for gcc and clang, Release build for MSCV) Otherwise, the result is meaningless.

Comment: I did try with gcc (C++14) with boost 1.60 and "-o2"- and second version is a little faster every time I run it.... (121ms and 118ms)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in the code, you've compiled this with

```
g++ ./main.cpp -o test -std=c++11
```

Since you didn't specify the optimization level, g++ used the default setting, which is `-O0` i.e. no optimization.

That means that the compiler didn't inline anything. Template libraries like the standard library or boost depend on inlining for performance. Additionally, the compiler will produce a lot of extra code, that's far from optimal -- it doesn't make any sense to make performance comparisons on such binaries.

Recompile with optimization enabled, and try your test again to get meaningful results.

Comment: Performances were indeed much better with -O3 flag, I got about 100ms for both methods using this flag. Thank you